# How can I set a CollectionViewCells image faster after scrolling through cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` that displays a list of items using high quality images.  To improve performance when scrolling, I've implanted the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
            var image = UIImage(data: item.image_data as! NSData)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, true, 0);
            image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.itemImage.image = image
            })
})
```

This has taken away all the lag from scrolling but is causing a new issue -  If I quickly scroll say 100 items, the cells I land on might change image 5-6 times before staying on the right image for that item.  I'm guessing this is just the `collectionView` playing catch-up.

So I need to have both smooth scrolling and the images displaying correctly as quickly as possible.  What's the most efficient way to get the best of both worlds?

I tried pre-loading the images in `viewDidLoad()` then slot that in as needed but this turned out to be a disastrous idea with memory.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe it's because you're updating the itemImage of the exact same cells returned based on re-use mechanism... thus each time a new cell gets displayed you end up doing background downloading that will then - once done - update one of the cell in the reuse stack, etc.

You should add an extra level to populate an array of images based on the row number and see if the row is still on screen before updating the cell and using the images you already got - if any - once a new cell appears on screen.